# how can i separately change contents of tags with a specific property

Tags: jquery, html

I have 4 "td" tags in my page. every "td" includes a "date and time" like this:

```
<td nowrap="">
  25/6/1392 14:34
</td>
```

I want to change the place of day and year, like: 1392/6/25  14:34

I used below code:

```
 var van=$("td [nowrap='']:contains('/1392')").text();
    var too=van.split(' ');
    var tri=too[0];
    var fouur=tri.split('/');
    $("td [nowrap='']:contains('/1392')").text(fouur[2]+'/'+fouur[1]+'/'+fouur[0]+' '+too[1]);
```

but this code just changes the first td content to what I want and changes all other td contents to the first td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be a space between `td` and `[nowrap='']`, if you have a space then it will be considered as the [descedant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
var van=$("td[nowrap='']:contains('/1392')").text();
var too=$.trim(van).split(' ');
var tri=too[0];
var fouur=tri.split('/');

$("td[nowrap='']:contains('/1392')").text(fouur[2]+'/'+fouur[1]+'/'+fouur[0]+' '+too[1]);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L5xXu/)

It should be as simple as

```
$("td[nowrap='']:contains('/1392')").text(function(idx, text){
    return text.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)(?=\s)/, '$3/$2/$1')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jvEQh/)

Comment: @user1336028 check the attached fiddle.. there was anoter problem with `$.trim(van).split(' ')`

Comment: @user1336028 in the result panel you can see `1392/6/25 14:34`